# Negate A Destructured Value Assigned To A New Variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have the following code in a React component.

```
const { isDisclosed: showDisclosureButton } = this.state
```

The problem is that I need the value of `showDisclosureButton` to be a negation of `this.state.isDisclosed`. The equivalent of:

```
const showDisclosureButton = !this.state.isDisclosed
```

Is there any way to negate a destructured value that is being assigned to a new variable?

Comment: I think there is no way

Comment: why not use : `const { isDisclosed } = this.state;
const showDisclosureButton = !isDisclosed;`

Comment: @Troopers Thanks. Yes I think that is the best option.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49571990/1048572

Comment: @Troopers Why use destructuring at all? But if you are a fan: `const {state: {isDisclosed}} = this;` :P

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. Just write

```
const showDisclosureButton = !this.state.isDisclosed
```

It is simple, clear, and shorter than any destructuring could be.