# Assign result of operation on destructured value to variable

Tags: javascript

I'm going to start with an example of what I wish to achieve:

1. I receive a string in this format `val1,val2,val3`
2. I would like to convert this to `[val1, val2, val3]`
3. This can be done quite easily with `"val1,val2,val3".split(,)`
4. Since I am using express, I get this string like this: `const {myStr} = req.query`
5. Instead of doing something like this:

```js
// Assume I'm using JSON for the sake of this example, I can use only strings
const { myStr } = req.body;

const myArr = myStr.split(',');
```

Is there a way to merge these two lines? I don't need `myStr` anywhere else. Thanks!

Comment: `const myArr = req.body.myStr.split(',');`?

Comment: That can be done... but I'm also destructuring other values, from `req.body`. I just wanted to know if this was possible!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the better you can get is something like this:

```
const { myStr, myArr = myStr.split(',') } = req.body;
```

I grabbed it from here: [ES6: change a value while destructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54345417/12136510)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with having two lines of code for this, but if you want a single line, you could do:

```js
const myArr = req.body.myStr.split(",");
```

You shouldn't be afraid of creating variables, sometimes we do a very difficult and abstract code just because we want to write less.

Always write simple and understandable code.